# Hall Sensor Diagnostic

Tags: electronics

I'm looking for some help with an ID3 Glacier Point 3D printer that I currently use. The hall sensors on one end of the X and Y axes have stopped functioning. I need to diagnose and confirm that the hall sensors are faulty before I can replace them (work stipulation.) I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of some diagnostic technique to detect faulty hall sensors? Google hasn't been much of an aid here, unfortunately.
[image: image of sensor]

Comment: A photo of the sensor might help. Does the firmware show any diagnostics for this sensor with the axis positioning information?

Comment: I am. I was able to isolate the bad sensor using a continuity test (simple, but I'm new to this.) Attached is the bad sensor that I took out. It's a long shot, but I don't suppose you'd know where I can find a replacement sensor?

https://imgur.com/a/Y5Oki

Answer (score 1):

It's really pretty easy to diagnose a [Hall effect sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor). If you plug the sensor into the board (so it has power), then wave a metal object (screwdriver tip should work nicely) very close to the head of the sensor, the light should go on if it's reading. If the light doesn't come on, there's an issue. An issue would most likely be the wiring. You may want to test the same sensor by plugging it into a known good port on your main board. Any of the axis stops should behave the same, but since it's both the x- and y-axis sensors which are not functioning, I'd try attaching them to the z-axis stop.